Splitting of composition of trace and counit in derived setting
Let $X,Y$ be varieties (separated of finite type schemes) over base field $k$, $\mathcal{F}$ be constructible sheaf on $Y_{\mathrm{et}}$ and assume that we have a finite morphism $f: X \to Y$, which guarantees (see e.g. these notes on p54) there exist a well-defined "trace map"
$$\text{tr}: f_{!}f^*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$$
As finite morphisms are proper we have $f_*=f_{!}$ and so we can precompose with counit map obtaining the composition which transfers into derived world - we work here with derived category $D_c^b(X)$  of constructible sheaves on $X_{et}$ (...or, if we additionally require $\mathcal{F}$ to be $l$-adic sheaf (for $\ell$ prime in $k$) we shall also reason on derived cat $D_c^b(X, \ell)$ of constructible $\ell$-adic sheaves):
$$\mathcal{F} \to  Rf_*f^* \mathcal{F}=Rf_{!}f^*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$$
Question: Which assumptions on $\mathcal{F}$ guarantee that this map actaully splits in sense of that $\mathcal{F} $ becomes direct summand of $Rf_{!}f^*\mathcal{F}$ in derived category?
It is well known that this composition coincides with multiplication by degree of $f$, and the I'm wondering when we actually have that $\mathcal{F}$ appears as direct summand of middle object.
An idea: can we recognize this composition as part of an valid exact triangle with one zero map, compare with this question?

Jeremy Rickard's argument in the comments of your other question gives the solution.  If $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to A$ have $g \circ f$ an isomorphism $A \to A$, then there exists $g'\colon B \to A$ such that $g' \circ f $ is $id_A$. Indeed, we can just take $g'=(g \circ f)^{-1} \circ g$.
Now form the distinguished triangle $C[-1] \to A \to B \to C$ completing $f$. Then $C[-1]\to A$ composed with $f$ is zero, so composed with $g \circ f$ is zero, but $g\circ f$ is the identity, so $C[-1]\to A$ must be $0$. Now since one morphism of the distinguished triangle is isomorphic to the distinguished triangle $  A\to A\oplus C \to C $, the whole triangle must be isomorphic to the distinguished triangle $A \to A\oplus C \to C$, giving the desired splitting.
